How do I enable all the formatting buttons in the Gitbook GUI
The gitbook documentation describes supported markup syntax, and I can confirm that I can use native Markdown like ## or indentation > when I push it directly via code. However there are not corresponding toolbar buttons for these formats.
Is there a way to enable these buttons in the GUI? I can't find any caveats anywhere. I've cross-posted this to Gitbook docs repo.


OK, turns out I was bamboozled. The interface converts markdown as you type it, so the toolbar is just a subset of what you can do by just typing.
